# what is JMS and what is RabbitMq and we when we choose what

Tags: jms, rabbitmq

I'm a little bit confused between JMS and RabbitMQ.
what is scenario when we have to use JMS and when We have to use RabbitMQ.

Comment: Such questions are offtopic on SO, see this help sections for details - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Incorrect question `RabbitMQ` is a type of JMS just like `Apaches activmq` or `IBMs websphere`. Each may have their own pros and cons. If you are new to JMS I would suggest start with activemq.

Comment: @AniketThakur not sure about "RabbitMQ is a type of JMS".

Comment: Read here: https://dzone.com/articles/jms-vs-rabbitmq. Google search just a bit, helps you know.